# Find all files with inconsistent newlines

Tags: newlines

I have a directory with a large number of files (in various subdirectories) and I need to find all files that have inconsistent newlines (i.e. a mixture of Windows and Unix line endings).

How could that be achieved (preferably on Windows, but a Linux approach but also be great).

By the way: As the relevant files are mostly XML, it would also help to have a method that analyses only the XML files.

Comment: The answers and comments to this question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255747/on-windows-how-would-i-detect-the-line-ending-of-a-file -- will help you detect which type a given file has. But if you have a file with both types, that will get trickier. What is the end goal? For example, if you want to convert them all to Unix-style, don't bother detecting -- just convert.

Comment: @DougDeden I suspect that a tool creates these "broken" files. Fixing them once does not help me much, I want to find out which files have mixed newlines, so that I can figure out what originally causes the problem.